# Eclipse IDE shows ">" at every indentation

Tags: php, eclipse

Eclipse IDE shows ">" at every indentation.

Every time I press `tab`, `>` is showing in my project.
My eclipse version is 3.7.2.

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Question is too short. Add some more details. When are you pressing tab,> any editors are active?Explain which view, perspective is active?

Comment: I mean - while I am coding in php file, ">" appear on page when I press "tab" key from keyboard(like "down arrow" appearing when we press "enter" key on page). If I press tab key twice, ">" appears twice.

Answer (score 1):

It's just showing you the indentions in your code. To disable this feature:

1) Click on `Window` then `Preferences`

2) Go to `General > Editors > Text editors`

3) Unckeck Show `whitespace characters`

4) Finaly click `OK`

Comment: I already found from internet and already tried as your way (Uncheck whitespace characters). It still happens. Thanks all.

Comment: May be. I also think it is indention problem. Does anyone have any idea how can I solve it?